# Get the directory name (not a path) of a given file path in Golang

Tags: regex, go, path, directory, filepath

By using the [`path/filepath`](https://golang.org/pkg/path/filepath/) package with the following example, you can get the full directory path from a file path.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "path/filepath"
)

func main() {
    // Output: /path/to/dir
    fmt.Println(filepath.Dir("/path//to/dir/file.ext"))
}
```

But is there a `Parent` function to get the `dir` from the path? (*which is the name of the directory of the file*):

```
// The `Parent` is what I want,
// and this is a pseudo-code example, this won't actually work.
//
// Output: dir
fmt.Println(filepath.Parent("/path//to/dir/file.ext"))
```

If it can't be done with the functions, how do I get the parent's name with RegExp?

Comment: `filepath.Dir` and `filepath.Base`?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can use `filepath.Base` to get the last element of the directory.
For example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "path/filepath"
)

func main() {
    paths := []string{
        "/home/arnie/amelia.jpg",
        "/mnt/photos/",
        "rabbit.jpg",
        "/usr/local//go",
    }
    for _, p := range paths {
        dir := filepath.Dir(p)
        parent := filepath.Base(dir)
        fmt.Printf("input: %q\n\tdir: %q\n\tparent: %q\n", p, dir, parent)
    }
}
```

Returns:

```
input: "/home/arnie/amelia.jpg"
    dir: "/home/arnie"
    parent: "arnie"
input: "/mnt/photos/"
    dir: "/mnt/photos"
    parent: "photos"
input: "rabbit.jpg"
    dir: "."
    parent: "."
input: "/usr/local//go"
    dir: "/usr/local"
    parent: "local"
```

(example adapted from the [filepath examples](https://golang.org/pkg/path/filepath/#pkg-examples))